# How to setup bootstrap-material-design react for theme overwrite

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-material-design

I am looking to start a new react project and I was hopeful about using [bootstrap-material-design](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/) but I'm not sure how to setup the project to overwrite the theme. The documentation talks about adding custom sass but I am not familiar with sass. I was hoping someone knew what step you need to get this working. I've created a fresh react app with npx create-react-app and installed the package with npm via `npm install bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1`. I've also added a `scss` folder at the root level of the project with a `custom.scss` file in that folder. currently the only code added to that file is an import of their sass files with `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` but nothing seems to happen when I add a material design component such as a Navbar. I also import the custom.scss file in the `index.js` file with `import './scss/custom.scss';` but I am still getting the following error: `File to import not found or unreadable: ../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.`

I guess my question is has anyone successfully used this package in a react project by using npm to install rather than using the cdn and if so can they tell me the steps require to get this up and running so I can re-theme bootstrap-material-design with my own branding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install required package
   `npm install bootstrap-material-design node-sass`
2. Add SASS path
   open `.env`, add following magic
   `SASS_PATH=node_modules:src` or `SASS_PATH=./node_modules;./src` for windows
3. Rename App.css to App.scss
4. Open App.scss
   Add following code: `@import 'bootstrap-material-design/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss';`

So far work for me.